# How to avoid the comment lines for parsing during string replacement in a file?

Tags: regex, perl

I am unable to avoid the comment lines(lines starting with *) for parsing during string replacement in a file. Please help me with my code.

```
`perl -pi.bak -e "$_ =~/[#.*]*/; /s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT STRING/g" Test.txt`;
```

Am using Perl in Eclipse,Windows XP.

I get the following Error message:

```
Number found where operator expected at -e line 6, near "*    LAST UPDATED 09/15"
(Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 1)
(Missing operator before 15?)
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 6, near "1994 AT"
(Missing operator before AT?)
```

Thanks in Advance,
Perl Newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `next` to skip the following code if you match a comment:

```
perl -i.back -p -e'next if /^#/; s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT STRING/' Test.txt
```

**update**: now as choroba suggested, instead of launching a separate instance of Perl and having to deal with quotes, you should probably have the whole thing in your main code:

```
my $file= 'Test.txt';
my $bak= "$file.bak";

rename $file, $bak or die "cannot rename $file into $bak: $!";;

open( my $in,  '<', $bak)  or die "cannot open $bak: $!";
open( my $out, '>', $file) or die "cannot create $file: $!";

while( <$in>)
  { if( ! /^\*/) # note the backslash here, * is a meta character
      { s/PERFORM \Q$func[5]\E\[\.\]*/# PERFORM $func[5]\.\n $hash{$func[5]}/g; }
    print {$out} $_;
  }
close $in; 
close $out;
```

Note that `$func[5]` can (potentially) includes meta-characters, so I used `\Q` and `\E` to escape them.

I am not sure about the `\[\.\]*` part, which as written matches a square bracket, a dot, and 0 or more closing square brackets: `[.`, `[.]`, or `[.]]`. I suspect that's not what you want.

Comment: No luck with that too.. :( BTW single quotes aren't valid in Windows.. i have to give the substitution expression in double quotes..

Comment: well, at least the code inside the (wrong) quotes works. Now you have to deal with Windows quoting rules.

Comment: BTW, giving us the PATTERN and REPLACEMENT STRING may be a good idea, so we can see if there are problems with those too

Comment: `perl -pi.bak -e "next if /^*/; s/PERFORM $func[5]\[\.\]*/#  PERFORM $func[5]\.\n $hash{$func[5]}/g" Test.txt`;

Comment: Wow..!  That worked like a charm.. :) But I need to put it in a loop for thoousand array elements.... Isn't it a humongous task opening and closing the file again nd again...?

Comment: which array elements? the ones in `@func`? It may be more productive if you had asked the whole question at once. As it is you keep asking for fragments of solutions when I suspect that the code that would solve your problem is pretty simple, something like `s/PERFORM (\w+)/#PERFORM $1\n $hash{$1}/` or, if the list of 'things to replace' is in `@funcs` create a hash `%func= map { $_ => 1 } @func`, then `s/PERFORM (\w+)/$hash{$1} ? "#PERFORM $1\n $hash{$1}" : "PERFORM $1"/e` to replace only the proper PERFORM

Comment: *@func* array contains the PATTERN... Then I am creating a %hash whose Key is PATTERN and corresponding Value is REPLACEMENT STING.. 
*@func* has around 1000 elements, hence I had opted for inline editing(which I think is faster)    { s/PERFORM \Q$func[5]\E\[\.\]*/# PERFORM $func[5]\.\n $hash{$func[5]}/g; }
works fine, but I fail to understand why    P5X98A-SET-CNOF-SW-S string also gets replaced during replacement of   P5X98A-SET-CNOF-SW
 thereby giving as output as #  #  PERFORM P5X98A-SET-CNOF-SW *some content here* finally ending with -S

Comment: I believe the initial question has been answered. If you need further help, open a new question, you'll get more eyeballs than by extending this comment thread that no one but me will read, and I am busy today.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)  Reaaly appreciate your help and time

Answer (score 2):

You should do the replacement only if the string does not match:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT STRING/g unless /^#/" Test.txt
```

Also, it seems you are trying to call Perl from Perl. That is usually slower than processing the file from inside your original program.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Note it treats `#` as the comment indicator, not `*` you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Works for me with `/^\*/` on Linux. Maybe double the backslash?

Comment: Test it with something simple, proceed in steps: `perl -i.bak -p -e "s/./X/g unless /^\*/"`

Answer (score 1):

I use this to skip the lines that match the regex

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\*/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you try to skip any lines which starting with '*' as the comments:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT STRING/g unless /^\*/" Test.txt
```

When processing a file like this:

```
* this is a comments: AAA => BBB
AAA
AAB
ABB
BBB
```

run

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/AAA/BBB/g unless /^\*/" Test.txt
```

you will get

```
* this is a comments: AAA => BBB
BBB
AAB
ABB
BBB
```

Only the AAA in the normal context will be replaced.